# a tag inside div-class

Tags: html, css, class, tags

Can I place `<a href="#">test</a>` inside `<div class="test">`

I am well aware of `<div class="test"> <a href="#">test</a> </div>`
my problem with that code is that the a tag leaves some styling for me to do in the css and i would be happy to shrink down my code as much as possible.

Comment: How else would you place an anchor in a div?

Comment: well, i wouldn't be asking if i knew there wasn't any other way....

Comment: Nope, that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely! There is no reason why an anchor can't reside within a div:

```
<div class="test">
  <a href="#">test</a>
</div>
```

Is perfectly valid syntax.

```
<body>
  <a class="test2" href="#">test</a>
</body>
```

Is also perfectly valid syntax.

It really just comes down to how you want to apply your styling. You can use either:

```
.test a {
  // Style the whole DIV, which can contain multiple <a> tags
}
```

Or:

```
.test2 {
  // Style the <a> tags that match the class `test2`.
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: The OP already knows that's valid syntax. He's looking for some shorter, alternative way.

Comment: hmm. i didn't think of putting the class inside the anchor. will try it out.

Comment: thank you Obsidian Age :) I just deleted 8 lines in my css. i guess i just got blink on my work.